# How to add a class to wordpress buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to add a class to the download button of all the posts of my wordpress site, but without having to do it in each post

I have umami software running, where I track my traffic, I would like to add events every time someone presses the download button

For that event to be registered, I must add the class "umami--click--download-button" to each button.

I have already tried in many ways but nothing seems to work
the last thing i did was add the following script but it doesn't work either

```
<script>
$( "div" ).addClass(function( index, currentClass ) {
  var addedClass;
 
  if ( currentClass === "wp-block-button" ) {
    addedClass = "umami--click--download-button";
  }
 
  return addedClass;
});
</script>
```

In the element inspector the button appears as follows

```
<div class="wp-block-button has-custom-font-size has-large-font-size">
<a class="wp-block-button__link has-white-color 
has-vivid-cyan-blue-to-vivid-purple-gradient-background 
has-text-color has-background wp-element-button" href="https://earnlink.click/" 
style="border-radius:10px" target="_blank"
rel="noreferrer noopener">DOWNLOAD</a></div>
```

Thank you very much in advance to whoever answers

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: yes, add this script after the <body> tag

Answer (score 0):

you need to test the entire class list.  see example below.  This will add the class to the <div> tag not the <a> tag.

```js
$("div").addClass(function(index, currentClass) {
  var addedClass;

  if (currentClass === "wp-block-button has-custom-font-size has-large-font-size") {
    addedClass = "umami--click--download-button";
  }

  return addedClass;
});
```

```css
.umami--click--download-button {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<div class="wp-block-button has-custom-font-size has-large-font-size">this is a test
  <a class="wp-block-button__link has-white-color 
has-vivid-cyan-blue-to-vivid-purple-gradient-background 
has-text-color has-background wp-element-button" href="https://earnlink.click/" style="border-radius:10px" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">DOWNLOAD</a></div>


<div class="wp-block-button has-custom-font-size has-large-font-size">this is a test another test</div>

<div class="wp-block-button ">and another</div>
```

Comment: I add all the classes and nothing happens, in your example you add an id=test that my button does not have and I have no way to add an id=
if it had id it would be easier to track it since I don't have to add the class to it

Comment: i removed the id='test' and it still works here.  This is the answer to your problem as stated.  If it's not working for you it's because of something else on your website.  Can you post a link to your website?

Comment: hello thanks for your help, it didn't work for me because I'm using wordpress, I had to add the jquery code to a file, add that file in a folder of my theme, and then add a code to the funtions.php file so that it executes that file with the jquery code, it took several hours but I already got the result and the records I need, I really appreciate your help, it was very important

Comment: If the answer works please accept it so others know it work!  thnks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code. Try this and let me know if it works fine or not. If you see any error in console please provide the error message for debugging

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $('div.wp-block-button .wp-block-button__link').each(function () {
            const classToAdd = 'umami--click--download-button';
            const button = $(this);
            if (!button.hasClass(classToAdd)) {
                button.addClass(classToAdd);
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, I don't know why it's so complex, it doesn't add the class to the button

Comment: Where are you putting this script code, can you tell?

Comment: after the <body> tag

Comment: it won't work there. you need to put it footer part before closing body

Comment: no, nothing works for me, in the same way I thank you for the effort